# When I open the keyboard my root view is scrollup

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

When I open the keyboard  my root view is scroll up.

I'm creating a chat based UI screen where I have toolbar and recyclerview for chat messages, and reply msg layout.

Whenever edittext get focus It moves up the toolbar. Instead I would like to resize the recyclerview.

some of the stackoverflow answers suggest to place a empty scrollview below the toolbar, but It didn't work.

Thanks in advance

My xml code is -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

    </data>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/album_dp_20"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/dp20">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/back"
                        android:layout_width="24dp"
                        android:layout_height="24dp"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/backbutton" />


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                        style="@style/Text_title_black_bold"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:text="@string/comment"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/dp20" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
        </LinearLayout>


        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@id/bottomLL"
            android:layout_below="@id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_10"
            tools:listitem="@layout/list_item_comments" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottomLL"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/dp_32"
            android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/album_dp_20"
            android:background="@drawable/et_background"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/gray"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/commentsTV"
                style="@style/Text_title_gray_black_bold"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.5"
                android:background="@null"
                android:hint="Write Message..."
                android:inputType="textAutoComplete"
                android:paddingVertical="@dimen/dp_10"
                android:textColor="#454545"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_64px" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_buzz"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/dp60"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:background="@drawable/et_background"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/red"
                android:fontFamily="@font/segoeui"
                android:text="Post"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_64px"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/progress"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="#6BE1E1D1"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <com.github.ybq.android.spinkit.SpinKitView
                style="@style/SpinKitView.Large.WanderingCubes"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/dp75"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                app:SpinKit_Color="@color/red_dark" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</layout>
```

I am using in my menifest -

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```